# How to make QSound synchronously?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, exit

How to make QSound synchronously?

I have an exit button. If I click on it I want play sound and then exit program. QSound is asynchronously and I don't know how to make it synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to play the sound synchronously. Anything that may block the GUI thread for more than 0.10 seconds shouldn't be done there, have a look [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Blocking_the_event_loop) for more information.

Since you are willing to play a sound when the user clicks the exit button, I think that using [`QSoundEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html) is better for your case, from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html#details):

> This class allows you to play uncompressed audio files (typically WAV files) in a generally lower latency way, and **is suitable for "feedback" type sounds in response to user actions** (e.g. virtual keyboard sounds, positive or negative feedback for popup dialogs, or game sounds).

`QSoundEffect` has a signal [`playingChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html#playingChanged) that you can leverage to close the application only when the sound has finished playing. I don't know why `QSound` does not have a similar signal though.

Here is a minimal example that explains how that may be done:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia>

class Widget : public QWidget {
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget* parent= nullptr):QWidget(parent) {
        //set up layout
        layout.addWidget(&exitButton);
        //initialize sound effect with a sound file
        exitSoundEffect.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("soundfile.wav"));
        //play sound effect when Exit is pressed
        connect(&exitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, &exitSoundEffect, &QSoundEffect::play);
        //close the widget when the sound effect finishes playing
        connect(&exitSoundEffect, &QSoundEffect::playingChanged, this, [this]{
            if(!exitSoundEffect.isPlaying()) close();
        });
    }
    ~Widget() = default;
private:
    QVBoxLayout layout{this};
    QPushButton exitButton{"Exit"};
    QSoundEffect exitSoundEffect;
};

//sample application
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Note that the above solution does not close the window until the sound effect finishes playing.

Another approach, that may seem more responsive for the application user, is to close the window, play the sound while the window is closed, and then quit the application when done playing. But this requires disabling the implicit quit when the last window is closed at the application level ([`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop)).

As a result of disabling the implicit quit, you have to add `qApp->quit();` on every possible exit path of your program. Here is an example showing the second approach:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia>

class Widget : public QWidget {
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget* parent= nullptr):QWidget(parent) {
        //set up layout
        layout.addWidget(&exitButton);
        //initialize sound effect with a sound file
        exitSoundEffect.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("soundfile.wav"));
        //play sound effect and close widget when exit button is pressed
        connect(&exitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, &exitSoundEffect, &QSoundEffect::play);
        connect(&exitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::close);
        //quit application when the sound effect finishes playing
        connect(&exitSoundEffect, &QSoundEffect::playingChanged, this, [this]{
            if(!exitSoundEffect.isPlaying()) qApp->quit();
        });
    }
    ~Widget() = default;
private:
    QVBoxLayout layout{this};
    QPushButton exitButton{"Exit"};
    QSoundEffect exitSoundEffect;
};

//sample application
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //disable implicit quit when last window is closed
    a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```